# Lookahead regular expression - Identify duplicate consecutive letters

Tags: regex, go

I have a string - for example, "Hello Worrld". Notice the "r" letter repeats twice.

I wish to identify letters that occur consecutively (two or more times) and retain only one of them. That is, I wish to get "Hello World" with a single "r".

Golang does not seem to have lookahead regular expression.

I tried using the following regular expression to identify letters that repeat consecutively -

```
r := regexp.Compile(`(.)\1`)
```

But it selects both the occurrences of the letters - I would want only one of them to be selected.

Comment: You would also want `Hello` to become `Helo`, right? Th expression should be `(.)\1+` to catch `wooorrrrrrld` as well.

Comment: Oh yeah. Correct. Expectation is to identify all letters that repeat consecutively and just retain only one of it.

Comment: I am not familiar with regex library in go, so I have no idea how it is done, but there should be a way to retrieve the first capturing group, which corresponds to the dot in parentheses. The whole expression, which in many regex implementations corresponds to group zero, will match all identical letters, but the first capturing group would be just the first character.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Go uses [`re2`](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use pcre bindings, however if you just want to remove dup letters you could use [`strings.Map`](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Map), for example:

```
func stripDups(s string) string {
    var last rune
    return strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
        if r != last {
            last = r
            return r
        }
        return -1
    }, s)
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/tAvnd8Kf7R)

Comment: Beautiful. Works as expected. Removes consecutive duplicate letters retaining only one of them.